# Instantiate Svelte Component in HTML5 Custom Tag (without Shadow DOM)

Tags: javascript, svelte, custom-element, svelte-3, svelte-component

I'm building a Svelte component library to be consumed using JavaScript only. At a later stage also by other Svelte applications as an additional option.

I want to avoid Svelte's custom element feature, since there are limitations with true Web Components and its Shadow DOM.

Currently the component is instantiated like this:

```html
<div id="my-component"></div>
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
        new MySvelteComponent({
            target: document.getElementById("my-component"),
            props: {
                firstProp: true,
                secondProp: "some value"
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Now I would like to provide a more elegant way by defining a HTLM5 custom tag like:

```html
<my-component firstProp="true" secondProp="some value">
```

What is a good way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

found it: [github/svelte-tag](https://github.com/crisward/svelte-tag) [npm/svelte-tag](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svelte-tag)

see regarding [issue on github](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/1748) near to the bottom is the answer from chrisward.

It makes a custom element but without shadow DOM. Found it today and workes for me.